# How to produce a single sign-in for 3 websites

Tags: asp.net, web-services, single-sign-on

I have 3 websites, and all my sites are using a common database. I want to have a single login control for all my sites.

I am thinking about having a solution using webservices, can anyone share if you can suggest me any other better solution?

All my sites are developed with ASP.NET technology.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [OpenID](http://openid.net/), or consider letting users [log in with Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) or other services, like the Stack Exchange network does.

**EDIT:** if you don't want to use a third-party service, you can deploy an [OAuth provider](http://oauth.net/) then. Notice that OAuth is a standard, not a service, like OpenID or Facebook Auth or similar solutions. It just saves you the hassle of actually designing the authentication process. You might be interested in the [code section](http://oauth.net/code/) of the OAuth site, as it contains open-source implementations in ASP.net.

Comment: thank you, actually i don't want to use a third party solution. I want to build my own solution. So is it a good idea to have a webservice for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You may think aobut `OpenID login` system as it is with StackExchange sites. And of course the `web-service` is the better solution to design a single sign-in authentication & authorization.

Comment: thank you, actually i don't want to use a third party solution. I want to build my own solution. So is it a good idea to have a webservice for this purpose?

Comment: @ Lucky Luck - Of course If you don't want to use existing services then develop it at your.